Logging library errors when connecting to Databricks JDBC
So, I'm using Java 17, Spring-Boot 3.2.10, Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.13 and DatabricksJDBC42.jar version 2.6.40 from https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-archive. And I'm seeing below errors at the start of the app
2024-12-10T08:15:11.192Z  INFO 1 --- [age 0.0 (TID 0)] o.a.s.e.Executor                         : Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
2024-12-10T08:15:11.853Z  INFO 1 --- [age 0.0 (TID 0)] o.a.s.s.c.e.c.CodeGenerator              : Code generated in 6.92667 ms
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for bundle
 java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ResourceBundleLookup
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3925)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:84)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:105)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:135)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:74)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getDefault(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:266)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:146)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:230)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:60)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator.<clinit>(BaseAllocator.java:46)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.arrow.ArrowBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.jdbc.SparkJDBC42Driver.createArrowBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.makeRowsetBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.dataengine.BackgroundFetcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCResultSet.moveToNextRow(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.BaseForwardResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx
 java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ContextMapLookup
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3925)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:84)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:105)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:135)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:74)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getDefault(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:266)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:146)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:230)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:60)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator.<clinit>(BaseAllocator.java:46)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.arrow.ArrowBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.spark.jdbc.SparkJDBC42Driver.createArrowBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.makeRowsetBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.dataengine.BackgroundFetcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCResultSet.moveToNextRow(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.client.jdbc.common.BaseForwardResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for date
 java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.DateLookup
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3925) AND MORE LOGS LIKE THIS ENDING WITH ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2024-12-10T08:15:12.087Z  INFO 1 --- [age 0.0 (TID 0)] o.a.s.s.e.d.j.JDBCRDD                    : closed connection
2024-12-10T08:15:12.099Z  INFO 1 --- [age 0.0 (TID 0)] o.a.s.e.Executor                         : Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1541 bytes result sent to driver
2024-12-10T08:15:12.105Z  INFO 1 --- [result-getter-0] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager                   : Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 928 ms on gdp-job-management-67454b74d5-rhkg6 (executor driver) (1/1)
2024-12-10T08:15:12.106Z  INFO 1 --- [result-getter-0] o.a.s.s.TaskSchedulerImpl                : Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
2024-12-10T08:15:12.109Z  INFO 1 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler                     : ResultStage 0 (isEmpty at SparkDataSetUtil.java:134) finished in 1.146 s
2024-12-10T08:15:12.111Z  INFO 1 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler                     : Job 0 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
2024-12-10T08:15:12.111Z  INFO 1 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.s.s.TaskSchedulerImpl                : Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage finished
2024-12-10T08:15:12.112Z  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler                     : Job 0 finished: isEmpty at SparkDataSetUtil.java:134, took 1.223863 s
2024-12-10T08:15:12.125Z ERROR 1 --- [   scheduling-1] c.g.j.s.i.JobServiceImpl                 : {"MESSAGE":"ERROR : Fetching details of list of job(s), Caused By : Could not find job(s) for given filters.","log":"ERROR","TIMESTAMP":"2024-12-10T08:15:12.125167704Z"}
com.project.util.JobsNotFoundException: Could not find job(s) for given filters.

As you can see, the code is trying to fetch jobs in Databricks using some select statements. This is working when the app is in Java 8 and is using an old Spark Simba Driver. Are the java.lang.ClassCastExceptions causing "connection closed" log in turn causing the JobsNotFoundExceptions?
The logging libraries used in the project are:

org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.20.0 -> 2.21.1
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.20.0 -> 2.21.1
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core -> 2.21.1

